# The HTML5 doctype isn't magic, right?

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, doctype

We have some contractors working on a mobile project and they kept insisting that we had to use the HTML5 doctype to use any HTML5 features, like the doctype was a great big boolean switch.  I had to keep telling them that doctype really didn't matter that much. You could use HTML5 input types and touch events on an `application/xhtml+xml` page with a XHTML 1.1 Strict doctype, and the browser could care less.  Likewise, you could use the `<center>` tag with the HTML5 doctype and the text will be centered.

Obviously there are caveats about lower versions of IE going into quirks mode, but that's not an issue in our scope.  I personally didn't care what doctype they used but was bothered by their complete lack of understanding on this.  At least, until I saw the [jQuery Mobile page setup documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/pages/page-anatomy.html):

> A jQuery Mobile site must start with an HTML5 'doctype' to take full
>   advantage of all of the framework's features. (Older devices with
>   browsers that don't understand HTML5 will safely ignore the 'doctype'
>   and various custom attributes.)

Are there any features of HTML5 that require the new doctype?  This documentation is just wrong, right?

Comment: You're right as far as ordinary Web browsers are concerned, but pages served to a mobile device as XML are a bit different; I don't know the answer for that case.  I do know that in general, with XHTML served as XML, the browser is officially supposed to refuse to show a page with errors, whereas in most other cases, the browser is supposed to be nice about it.

Comment: My experience is that pages served as XML just validate against syntax errors, not semantic errors.  They will allow `<p><table/></p>` without issue.

Comment: I've never dealt with mobile devices, but it doesn't seem like this would be too hard to test if you have access to a mobile device (which I don't).

Comment: I think having a short doctype is actually one of the features of HTML5... so in that sense, the documentation's not wrong.

Comment: @Brilliand - It's not exactly that a browser must refuse to show a page with (well-formedness) errors, it's just that a XML parser, in a browser or not, must stop parsing an input stream as XML when it detects that the stream is not XML well-formed. The XML spec does not define what happens after that, and browsers do different things. Firefox refuses to display anything except an error message, but IE9 displays everything it has successfully parsed up to the point where it detected the well-formedness error. Chrome is similar to IE9, but also displays an error message.

Comment: @BrianNickel - If you serve your page only as `application/xhtml+xml` (not `application/xml+xhtml`), you actually don't need a doctype at all. Doctype switching only applies to `text/html` documents.

Comment: Here may be my comments is different then other but, In my Opinion DOCTYPE is very important. you need to tell browser, search engine, or anyone looking your code that you are work on HTML5. If you say you can use any other doctype and can use HTML5 features. In that case you can use it without use in DOCTYPE just start your HTML from <body>. But it's not the way.

Comment: @Alohci Fixed content type above.  (I assume that a page with that content type would trigger a file download dialog.)  That's an interesting point.  Poking around it seems that XHTML is supposed to derive its behavior not from the doctype but from the namespace.  It's odd, then, that so much weight has been placed on using the proper XHTML doctype in literature.  That said, it still doesn't do any real validation that you conform to the schema.  This page confirms your comment: http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/

Comment: @Tarun I believe you could have a page that is just `<canvas></canvas><script>...</script>` and it will work, even though it will be in quirks mode.  Depreciated elements are also supported. Browsers accept all elements they support, regardless of doctype or content type.  Search engines also likely won't care and accept `<aside>` from different doctypes.  Their goal is to provide best user experience, not conform to standards.  I would agree that a correct doctype helps with maintainability and clarifying intent (except for XHTML doctypes), but we're really focused on "magic."

Comment: @BrianNickel You are right, but now we are using HTML5. As you Know we can do anything with div. Then why we have section, article, aside, nav, header, footer etc. It's all about meaning full coding. Your code should make sense what is it all about. Doctype is like heading of your document. It's says to browsers, validators, and developers that "hye!! we are using HTML5"

Comment: @Tarun, that's not necessarily true.  If we use the HTML5 doctype, it isn't a license to use everything.  A developer may see the doctype and assume they can use `<aside>` even though they are targeting Android 2.1 which doesn't style it correctly.  They may also assume they can use `<video>` even though they are targeting IE8 or the `hidden` attribute though they are targeting IE9.  Doctype should be as meaningless to developers as it is to browsers (and it is quite meaningless).  What matters is knowing what features you can use for your target browser set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsers do not do anything magic with the `<!DOCTYPE html>` beyond putting the page into standards mode, and so it is equivalent to any other doctype that does the same thing.

However, it is a testable object in JavaScript, so it is *conceivable* that a piece of JS could do something stupid like switch its behaviour depending on the presence or not of a given doctype. Without going through the code line by line it's impossible to know whether the statement in the jQuery Mobile page setup documentation is specifically true, or just general advice that if followed will result in the desired outcome.

Comment: Looking at the source for both jQuery and jQuery mobile, there aren't any checks for `document.doctype`.  That's a good point, though.  Even though the browser doesn't care, someone could write a script that cares.

Answer (score 2):

As far as the common Web browsers running on desktops and laptops are concerned: The browser doesn't care very much about the doctype - it will use new features even if your doctype says they aren't allowed.  The doctype is really for the validator; your page won't validate unless the features you're using are allowed by the doctype you're using.

I can't actually speak for mobile devices, since I have next to no experience with them, but it seems like they would work similarly, since they're using the same browser rendering engines and attempting to access the same Internet.